# Some issue with random.choice and variables?

Tags: python, function, variables, random

I have a program that prints ou random things from a function, but it isn't exactly working right. All the program does is give blank output and nothing else. Here is an example of the program:

```
def funct1():
    print "Funct1"

def funct2():
    print "Funct2"

functs = [funct1, funct2]

def run():
    select_funct = random.choice(functs)

run()
```

Like I said, whenever I run this script, it just gives empty output. Can anyone help?

Comment: You pick a random function and then never call it... use `select_func()` after you've picked it for instance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You much invoke your function reference from **run**.

```
def run():
   select_funct = random.choice(functs)
   select_funct()
```

Comment: could it also be called like this: __thing = random.choice(list)()__ ? With the extra parentheses?